# Unexpected token 'export' for jest custom library

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have created my own custom library that I bundled to ES modules using vite as bundler. Then I successfully import it from node_modules like so:

```
import { create } from 'light-test'
```

Everything works fine but when I try to run the test that imports this module I get an error: `Unexpected token 'export'`, I tried to use transformIgnorePatterns in jest.config.js but this does not work.